# Unable to build a python app with AWS SAM

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying to build and run the sample `python` application from AWS SAM. I just installed python, below is what command lines gives..

```
D:\Udemy Work>python
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

D:\Udemy Work>pip -V
pip 21.1.3 from c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

When I run `sam build`, I get the following error

```
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.EXE', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python.EXE'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.8. Do you have python for runtime: python3.8 on your PATH?
```

Below is my code

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python-test

  Sample SAM Template for python-test

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

**app.py**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    Description: >
      python-test
    
      Sample SAM Template for python-test
    
    # More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 3
    
    Resources:
      HelloWorldFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: hello_world/
          Handler: app.lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.9
          Events:
            HelloWorld:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /hello
                Method: get
```

If I change the run time in yaml, then I get the following error

```
PS D:\Udemy Work\awslambda\python-test> sam build
Building codeuri: D:\Udemy Work\awslambda\python-test\hello_world runtime: python3.9 metadata: {} functions: ['HelloWorldFunction']

Build Failed
Error: 'python3.9' runtime is not supported
```

What is the solution here?

Comment: I had to edit template.yaml and set Runtime: python3.9

Answer (score 2):

`python3.9` is **not supported**. The supported runtimes are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) and the latest python that you can use is `python3.8`.

SAM [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html) docker through `--use-container` flag. Thus you can build your packages using it for any python version you want SAM.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How can I tell the AWS SAM to use 3.8?

Comment: @JustCause I think you would have to install python 3.8. I'm not sure if you can force sam to use different version that you have installed in your os.

Comment: thank you Marcin. I am new to Python. Install after uninstalling the current version? Or just install and python will figure it out?

Comment: @JustCause I would look at using docker or vm. Installing new python version at os level can mess up other software. But it depends on your os.

Comment: Understand. I am using Microsoft.

Comment: @JustCause SAM [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html) docker through `--use-container` flag. have you tried that? I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Python3.9 is now supported according to the link you gave.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2023 and Python 3.9 and 3.10 are now supported.

The example app for your course may still be targeting Python 3.7.

Just change to your desired version:

1. Update sam:

```
pip3 install -U aws-sam-cli
```

2. Open `template.yaml` and replace `Runtime: python3.7` with `Runtime: python3.10`

The error above should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure to update SAM CLI to latest version to support Python 3.9 runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30964619)